# succinct code for repetitive subsetting in R

Tags: r, subset

I am an R beginner and am having trouble finding a better way to recode an element of a dataframe. I have data which has a column with the year it was sampled (assessed), however I want to run some tests based on the biennial subset (not annual like it is formatted). Therefore I want two concurrent years to be identified by the assessment year. I think I could run something like:

```
ddd$Assessment[ddd$Assessment==1997 & ddd$Assessment==1998]<-1998
```

but feel there must be a better way (I know I don't need the second half of the code above but just left it in for clarity) especially as I have a lot of data spanning 23 years.
Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If your assessment year is consistently every other year, here is one way to create your biennial column by using the properties of the `ceiling` function.

```
ddd <- data.frame(Assessment = 1997:2006)
ddd$biennial <- ceiling(ddd$Assessment/2)*2
ddd
#   Assessment biennial
#1        1997    1998
#2        1998    1998
#3        1999    2000
#4        2000    2000
#5        2001    2002
#6        2002    2002
#7        2003    2004
#8        2004    2004
#9        2005    2006
#10       2006    2006
```

Comment: The ceiling function looks really useful thanks for bringing it to my attention. Yes, the data is collected annually but assessment performed biennially (even years are assessment years). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To code biennial years and make sure that no future user of the data-set is mistaken in what this column actually represents, I'd rather use `cut`:

```
ddd <- data.frame(Assessment = 1997:2006)
ddd$biennial <- cut(ddd$Assessment, breaks = seq(1996, 2008, by=2), right = F)
ddd
#   Assessment    biennial
#1        1997 [1996,1998)
#2        1998 [1998,2000)
#3        1999 [1998,2000)
#4        2000 [2000,2002)
#5        2001 [2000,2002)
#6        2002 [2002,2004)
#7        2003 [2002,2004)
#8        2004 [2004,2006)
#9        2005 [2004,2006)
#10       2006 [2006,2008)
```

Comment: Great! I can see plenty of uses for the cut function. Much appreciated!